# Não consigo pegar o valor de um input para comparar dentro de um _construct

Tags: php

Meu projeto faz cadastro de usuários e no banco de dados tenho uma tabela `User` e outra `Profile`. A `User` é para dados de *login* e senha, e a `Profile` para os dados pessoais. Mas agora preciso criar um novo tipo de `Profile`, ficando `ProfileEmpresa` e `ProfileCliente`. No formulário de cadastro tem `input hidden` dizendo qual o tipo de `profile` (1 ou 0), para direcionar os dados pra tabela certa.

O problema: na classe `Registrationcontrollerextention` não consigo pegar o valor do 'tipo' e fazer um `if/else` dentro do método `construct`.

**UPDATE:** Consegui resolver esse problema, mas mesmo gravando corretamente no BD aparece um erro na página.
Notice: Undefined variable: tipo in C:\xampp\htdocs\festas\controllers\authenticate\registrationcontrollerextention.php on line 24

```
class Registrationcontrollerextention{

private $registry;
private $extraFields = array();
private $errors = array();
private $submittedValues = array();
private $sanitizedValues = array();
private $errorLabels = array();
private $tipo;

public function __construct($registry )
{
    if(isset($_POST['register_tipo']))
        {
            $tipo = $_POST['register_tipo'];
            echo $tipo;
        }
          /* essa eh a linha 24 */
        if($tipo == 0)
        {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->extraFields['dino_name'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Name', 'table' => 'profileCliente', 'field' => 'dino_name', 'type' => 'text', 'required' => false );
        $this->extraFields['dino_breed'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Breed', 'table' => 'profileCliente', 'field' => 'dino_breed', 'type' => 'text', 'required' => false );
        $this->extraFields['dino_gender'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Gender', 'table' => 'profileCliente', 'field' => 'dino_gender', 'type' => 'text', 'required' => false);
        $this->extraFields['dino_dob'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Date of Birth', 'table' => 'profileCliente', 'field' => 'dino_dob', 'type' => 'DOB', 'required' => false );
        }
        else
        {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->extraFields['dino_name'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Name', 'table' => 'profileEmpresa', 'field' => 'dino_name', 'type' => 'text', 'required' => false );
        $this->extraFields['dino_breed'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Breed', 'table' => 'profileEmpresa', 'field' => 'dino_breed', 'type' => 'text', 'required' => false );
        $this->extraFields['dino_gender'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Gender', 'table' => 'profileEmpresa', 'field' => 'dino_gender', 'type' => 'text', 'required' => false);
        $this->extraFields['dino_dob'] = array( 'friendlyname' => 'Pet Dinosaurs Date of Birth', 'table' => 'profileEmpresa', 'field' => 'dino_dob', 'type' => 'DOB', 'required' => false );

        }
}
```

Este é o meu formulário

```
    <form action="authenticate/register" method="post" class="form-horizontal"  role="form"> 

                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="register_user" name="register_user" value="{register_user}" >

                        <input type="password" class="form-control"  id="register_password" name="register_password" value="" >

                        <input type="password" class="form-control"  id="register_password_confirm" name="register_password_confirm" value="" >

                        <input type="text" id="register_email" name="register_email" value="{register_email}" class="form-control" />

                        <input type="text" id="register_dino_name" name="register_dino_name" value="{register_dino_name}" class="form-control"/>

                        <input type="text" id="register_dino_breed" name="register_dino_breed" value="{register_dino_breed}" class="form-control" /><br /> 

                        <input type="text" id="register_dino_dob" name="register_dino_dob" value="{register_dino_dob}" class="form-control"/> 

                        <input type="submit" id="process_registration" name="process_registration" value="Enviar!" class="botao"/> 

                        <input type="hidden" id="register_tipo" name="register_tipo" value="1"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: coloca o fonte do teu formulário também pra podermos analisar melhor

Comment: Consegui resolver. Obrigada!!

Comment: @Rachel, que bom que resolveu. Se foi com alguma resposta, pode marcar, caso contrário, você pode descrever a solução para quem possa ter o mesmo problema que você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resposta referente ao erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: tipo

---

Repare que a variável `$tipo` só está sendo definida se `$_POST['register_tipo']` for enviado.

Você pode usar a forma abaixo e verificar se o campo foi enviado, caso contrário, você pode disparar uma *Exception*. Use `elseif` se você tem mais de duas opções. Também pode usar [**switch**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php) quando tiver mais opções para verificar.

---

```
public function __construct($registry )
{
    // verifica se o campo foi enviado
    if( ! isset( $_POST['register_tipo'] ) ){
        throw new Exception( "O campo 'register_tipo' não foi enviado" );
    } else {
        // verifica o tipo
        if( $_POST['register_tipo'] === 'um valor qualquer' ){
            // ...
        } elseif ( $_POST['register_tipo'] === 'outro valor qualquer' ){
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Apenas como ilustração, usei o operador de comparação idêntico (===). `$_POST` retorna uma string, logo, `$_POST['register_tipo'] === 0` vai falhar, pois a tipagem é diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Como o @PapaCharlie já disse, o erro `Undefined variable` é causado porque a **variável local** `$tipo` pode não ser devidamente definida se o código dentro do `IF` não for executado.

Porém, se a ideia é colocar o `register_tipo` no atributo `private $tipo` da classe, então faça `$this->tipo`, pois diferente de outras linguagens como Java, em PHP você não acessa atributos diretamente.

Mas, como o formulário postado possui o campo `name` com valor `register_tipo`, o problema não deveria ocorrer. Verifique se o `$_POST` está realmente recebendo esse valor.

De resto, *parece* que o código ia funcionar.